# "Service Requires SSL" error message while retrieving the tracking history of a message to a mobile number

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am just retrieve the tracking history of a message to a mobile number and I'm constructing a GET method by url, http://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/messageContact/MTM6NjI1OjA/history/LWt3YUtiLVA4RTJnSG1ISHlNMmhrZzo3OTow/mobileNumber/13175551212 and I'v added accessToken  as OAuth2Bearer token in GET request's header.

accessToken : wq68aqwk772su44zyqhkapk8.

I'm getting the following response :

```
 {
  "documentation" : "https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/403",
  "errorcode" : 0,
  "message" : "Service Requires SSL"
 }
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `http` in your request. You should be `https` instead. Look at the official API documentation [here](http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/getMessageContactDelivery.html).

I changed your URL to https and the error goes away (it gives not authorised because the `accessToken` has probably expired)

Comment: Happy to help, please mark this as an 'Answer' so that it helps others!

Comment: Hi Gaurav, the hyperlink you mentioned is working but I'm tring to using API document given in url, http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/getMessageContactHistory.html. The example request mentioned here is using http and I'm getting error message, "Service Requires SSL" as mentioned earlier. I tried to use https instead as you suggested and I got the following response , {
  "documentation" : "https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/404",
  "errorcode" : 404,
  "message" : "Not Found"
}